# eliminate null values in String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

I have a String array with some strings inside but they all start with the null value when i print them. How can i get rid of those null values or change the code so that they dont exist?

thanks you !
Heres what i wrote so far. im reading a file and saving the content in the array at the positions 0,1,2,3

```
    String [] matrix= new String[3];

    while ((line=br.readLine() ) != null){
//              level += line+"\n";
                matrix[k] += line+"\n";


            }
```

and i print the array like this

```
for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
            System.out.println(matrix[i]);

        }
```

Comment: what was the output? matrix[k] is never changed like k++ or anything

Comment: try changing `matrix[k] += line+"\n";` to `matrix[k++] += line+"\n";`

Comment: declare and initialise k? (int k = 0;)

Comment: if we kept voting down questions like this there would be no one left on stackoverflow. this is an actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a "+=", you are appending to an existing string, which was  initialized as "null" when you first create a String array. You could probably use the "=" as in below code to achieve what you are doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String [] matrix= new String[3];
    int i = 0;

while(i <= 2){
                matrix[i] = "This is new String" +"\n";

                i++;
            }

for (int j=0; j<3;j++){
            System.out.println(matrix[j]);

        }
}
```

Comment: i guess you gave this code as an sample ya? btw, nicely and clearly said so u got my +1

Comment: i still think he trying to append to previous values from the while loop. I'm not sure the index k in his code is the line number. an inline null check perhaps?  matrix[k] = (matrix[k] == null ? line : matrix[k] + line) + "\n";

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are seeing null is because you are going over a matrix array that is not initialized. The value k is never initialized and it is never modified while going through the while loop, so you overwrite the contents of matrix[k], whatever it is initialized to upon startup.